# Add a RTL SCSS file to zurb foundation 5

Tags: drupal-7, zurb-foundation, multilingual

Okay I have zurb installed on a drupal project and have it running with grunt, since it only has one main scss file [themename].scss and I'd like to have a multilingual website, I wondered how can I create a secondary .scss file for RTL pages, so it can override the main css file when viewing the RTL website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use foundation for building drupal themes. And here is how I handle rtl scss files.

Folder structure:

```
- scss/
    |
    - _settings.scss
    - _settings-rtl.scss
    - app.scss
    - app-rtl.scss
- bower_components/
- config.rb
```

`settings.scss`; Standard foundation `settings.scss` file.

`settings-rtl.scss`; import `settings.scss` at the beginning of the file (to inherit all define variables) and then override any values you want.

```
@import "settings";
$text-direction: rtl;
$opposite-direction: right;
// any other settings you want to override.
```

`app.scss`;

```
@import "settings";
@import "../bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize";
@import "../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation";
```

`app-rtl.scss`;

```
@import "settings-rtl";
@import "../bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize";
@import "../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't help you with the SCSS file but as for CSS you can just add another themename-rtl.css file manually to the CSS directory and start coding

Comment: Well thanks but as you can see I rather to have SCSS file instead of just adding another CSS file.